# Delphi: Form becomes Frozen while assigning strings in thread

Tags: multithreading, forms, delphi, freeze

A code below is in a thread.

```
Tf1 := TFileStream.Create(LogsPath,fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
...
str:=TStringList.Create;
str.LoadFromStream(tf1);
...
SynEditLog.Lines.Assign(str); // I do this with Synchronize
```

There are 30 000 strings in a text document.

A form becomes frozen while assigning those strings to SynEdit.

If to load string by string it takes me 40 sec... If to use Assign - 8 sec.

How to prevent this form's state?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why load into a string list first? Why not load directly into control? And I bet TMemo could load 30 000 lines in 8 seconds.

Comment: I make some operations there. It does not matter. I have checked. If to do directly - the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `Application.ProcessMessages` is going to help here at all, since all the work happens in the one call to `Assign`.

Does `SynEditLog` have `BeginUpdate`/`EndUpdate` methods? I'd use them and see how you go. For instance:

```
SynEditLog.BeginUpdate;
try
  SynEditLog.Lines.Assign(str);
finally
  SynEditLog.EndUpdate;
end;
```

**In response to that not working**

You'll need to break down the assignment of the string list to the Lines property. Something like this:

```
var
  LIndex: integer; 
begin
  SynEditLog.BeginUpdate;
  try
    //added: set the capacity before adding all the strings.
    SynEditLog.Lines.Capacity := str.Capacity;
    for LIndex := 0 to str.Count - 1 do
    begin
      SynEditLog.Lines.Add(str[LIndex]);
      if LIndex mod 100 = 0 then
        Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
  finally
    SynEditLog.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

(note: code typed directly into browser, may not compile)

If this is too slow, try increasing the `LIndex mod 100 = 0` to something larger, like 1000 or even 5000.

N@

Comment: It has BeginUpdate/EndUpdate. But it does not help too.

Comment: I cannot use loops. If to add strings using this method it takes me around 1 min!!! Assign - 8 sec.

Comment: Try setting the capacity of the Lines property first. I've updated my example.

Comment: Interesting that there is a disparity, that's all `TStrings.Assign` does.

Comment: I tried Lines.LoadFromFile, did not help (the same as Assign).

Comment: I'm beginning to think that SynEdit is not what you need then, if you're not happy with that 8 second delay. Not that I can offer an alternative, sorry.

Comment: if to use your code without BeginUpdate/EndUpdate - works!!! But it takes 1 min to add all strings...

Comment: You're hitting the limits here, you either have the UI responsive and wait longer, or you have it unresponsive and take less time. What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Delphi 2010. Do you want an example? Windows Notepad - becomes frozen as my program too. AkelaPad or Lister from Total Commander - opens a  file instantly!!!!

Comment: Do you have line wrapping turned on? Try turning it off first

Comment: The difference is that Total Commander and Lister probably don't load the whole file into memory at one time, or they use memory mapped files. They also wouldn't be loading the strings into one big list, then copying them over to another one.

Comment: I agree, it is memory mapped files. I do not use wrapping -> it is death to use it :)

Comment: @maxfax having no interaction with user whilst loading file is fine. What can the user safely do anyway when your app is in that state?

Answer (score 1):

The form is freezing because you're using the GUI thread to add 30,000 lines to your control, which naturally takes a while. During this time, the GUI can't update because you're using its thread, so it looks frozen.

One way around this would be to add a few lines (or just one) at a time, and, in between each add, update the GUI (by calling `Application.ProcessMessages` (thanks gordy)).

Comment: Does not help! I put ProcessMessages into a SpecialLineColors Event of a SynEdit, where I paint lines. To be more exactly  the SynEdit is on a frame.

Comment: You can't get around this with a ProcessMessages call.  That *ONE* line is going to take a bunch of time, you can't break it up.  You have to put the load into a background thread.

Comment: @maxfax You have to break up the lines manually, because Loren is correct, it's that _one_ line. By manually, I mean put them in a container, iterating it, adding one at a time, with calls to `ProcessMessages` in between however many you want.

Comment: It is impossible, if to do like this then it takes me 1 min to add all 30 000 strings.

Comment: Then you may have to choose whether to have your app freeze during the intense calculations or to have them add smoothly but take a while longer.

Comment: Windows Notepad - becomes frozen as my program too. AkelaPad or Lister from Total Commander - opens file instantly!!!!

Comment: @maxfax how can you tell it loads the whole file instantly? It probably loads only some at a time but you can only see some at a time, giving the appearance that it did it all at once.